# Can i use parameter for mysql "limit start, count"

Tags: mysql

I want to use stored procedure parameter as start and count in MySQL limit. But it seems limit only accepts constant values. How can i construct a sql in which start and limit is stored procedure parameter?

Comment: What's the question? Are you doubting the error you got when you tried?

Answer (score 2):

I really dont know, but I just feel like this will work for you.
[Untested]

```
DELIMITER $ 
CREATE PROCEDURE `tmp`() 
BEGIN 
PREPARE STMT FROM "SELECT * FROM yourTable LIMIT ?,?"; 
END$ 
DELIMITER; 

SET @a=2; 
SET @b=1; 

CALL tmp(); 
EXECUTE STMT USING @a, @b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the limit, offset and so on as a Java Prepared Statement parameter. Just try it out. (We're talking about Java, right?)